# How to extract the ID's of top two values in a column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, from which I need the ID's (index values) of top two values of a particular column.

Example

```
two_highest_degree_id=karate.nlargest(2,'degree')
```

karate is my dataframe and i need the index values of top two values of the column degree. The above script gave me the following result:

```
      club     degree  cluster_coef
33  Officer      17      0.110294
0    Mr. Hi      16      0.150000
```

how can I assign the index values `33`, & `0` to an output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([10,9,8,7,6,50], columns = ['degree'])

df.nlargest(2,'degree').index
#op
Int64Index([5, 0], dtype='int64')
```